# Java Web Strat ExitException: Permission denied

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a JNLP file and its JAR file in the same folder, once I double click the jnlp file, the java web start start working but immediately gives an ExitException: Permission denied to the mentioned path.

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After I read so many articles and questions on the internet, including create a new security policy file which grants the all permissions to the java web start, I just do the following:

1. first, there're multiple jre's configured on my machine, so I have deleted all paths and configurations which are related to the older versions.
2. I have changed the compatibility of the javaws.exe to be compatible with windows 7.
3. I have give my user the full control over the javaws.exe
4. I have cleared the cache of the java applications.

Then I tried and the java web start launching the application.